# Azure with Xamarin.forms Name resolution Failure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-app-service-plans

Currently trying to executing **Azure with forms** TO DO sample application.
When I executing I facing some issues

1. When I trying to publish the service there is no option for **Microsoft Azure App service** instead of that I am getting  **Microsoft Azure web app**
2. After run app (Emulator).when trying to add new record I am getting **Name Resolution Failure error**

Comment: please attach errors in detail

Answer (score 0):

Well... not a lot of details but I will give a try...

---

Go to your Azure Dashboard and look for your App Service to download the publish profile.

[image]

---

Now, import it on your Visual Studio Project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks daniel. i will check

Comment: @kiruphakaran Nice... I think it will work, I had similar issue last time, and it went fine... if not, just give more details on what is going on.